# DiscordJS embeds not adding fields properly

Tags: node.js, discord

I am programming my discord bot to work with google calendar. I've managed to get this code almost working https://pastebin.com/DRT83kcr, but there is a problem with that embed, it doesn't add these field into it. Why ? It logs them and values are right, but when it logs the embed, there are no fields. Can you please help me ?

```
// Funkce na vypisování skautských událostí
function listEvents(auth) {
  var fields = [];
  const embded = new Discord.MessageEmbed() // Vytvoření embedu
          .setColor("#0ddede")
          .setThumbnail("https://medvediberoun.eu/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/znak_oddilu.jpg") // Skautské logo
          .setTitle("Skaut")
          .setDescription("4 Nadcházející akce ve skautském kalendáři")
          .setTimestamp()
          .setAuthor('Medvědi Beroun', 'https://medvediberoun.eu/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/znak_oddilu.jpg', 'https://medvediberoun.eu/')
          .setFooter('https://www.skaut.cz/', 'https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.U8-xvll_vFXoDUbWx7AxCAHaHa%26pid%3DApi&f=1')
          .setURL("https://skaut.cz/");
  const calendar = google.calendar({version: 'v3', auth}); // Něco od googlu
  calendar.events.list({
    calendarId: 'primary',
    timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
    maxResults: 4,
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime',
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const events = res.data.items;
    if (events.length) {
      events.map((event, i) => {
        const start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
        fields.push([parseISOString(start).toDateString(),event.summary]);
      });
      console.log(fields);
      printEmbded(fields);
      
    } else {
      console.log('No upcoming events found.'); // Žádné eventy
    }
  }); 
}

function printEmbded(fields) {
  var fields = getAkce();
  console.log(fields);
  for(var index = 0; index < fields.length; index++){ // Procházení všech eventů
        console.log(fields[index][0] + " " + fields[index][1] + " " + index ); // Zpracování jednotlivých eventů 
        if(index == 0){ // Jestliže je první 
          embded.addFields({name: fields[index][0], value: fields[index][1], inline: false}, {name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B'}); // Vypsání samostaně
        } else {
          embded.addField(fields[index][0], fields[index][1], true); // Vypsání ostatních eventů
        }
      }
  console.log(embded);
  client.channels.cache.get(ids.skautAnouncements).send(embded);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any error ?
I think it's because you don't add your `embded` variable inside your `printEmbded()` function.

You should try :

```
// Funkce na vypisování skautských událostí
function listEvents(auth) {
  var fields = [];
  const embded = new Discord.MessageEmbed() // Vytvoření embedu
          .setColor("#0ddede")
          .setThumbnail("https://medvediberoun.eu/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/znak_oddilu.jpg") // Skautské logo
          .setTitle("Skaut")
          .setDescription("4 Nadcházející akce ve skautském kalendáři")
          .setTimestamp()
          .setAuthor('Medvědi Beroun', 'https://medvediberoun.eu/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/znak_oddilu.jpg', 'https://medvediberoun.eu/')
          .setFooter('https://www.skaut.cz/', 'https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.U8-xvll_vFXoDUbWx7AxCAHaHa%26pid%3DApi&f=1')
          .setURL("https://skaut.cz/");
  const calendar = google.calendar({version: 'v3', auth}); // Něco od googlu
  calendar.events.list({
    calendarId: 'primary',
    timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
    maxResults: 4,
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime',
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const events = res.data.items;
    if (events.length) {
      events.map((event, i) => {
        const start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
        fields.push([parseISOString(start).toDateString(),event.summary]);
      });
      console.log(fields);
      printEmbded(fields, embded);
      
    } else {
      console.log('No upcoming events found.'); // Žádné eventy
    }
  }); 
}

function printEmbded(fields, embded) {
  var fields = getAkce();
  console.log(fields);
  for(var index = 0; index < fields.length; index++){ // Procházení všech eventů
        console.log(fields[index][0] + " " + fields[index][1] + " " + index ); // Zpracování jednotlivých eventů 
        if(index == 0){ // Jestliže je první 
          embded.addFields({name: fields[index][0], value: fields[index][1], inline: false}, {name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B'}); // Vypsání samostaně
        } else {
          embded.addField(fields[index][0], fields[index][1], true); // Vypsání ostatních eventů
        }
      }
  console.log(embded);
  client.channels.cache.get(ids.skautAnouncements).send(embded);
}
```

Comment: no, it doesn't work at all, now it's not sending anything and it's giving that error https://pastebin.com/55Hv1Ya9